# How to run python code after running flask function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I have a python code below here:

```
def func1():
    return x
def func2():
    return y
x=func1()
y=func2()
z=x+y
products={} #its a nested dictionary containing product details 
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', z=z, x=x, y=y)
@app.route('/product/<key>')
def product(key):
    product = products.get(key)
    if not product:
    abort(404)
    return render_template('product.html', product=product)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug = True)
```

This is the basic structure of my code. If I run this entire program gets executed twice. Is there a way to launch the web browser first and then run the python code?

Comment: What do you mean by "gets executed twice"? What do you mean by "launch the web browser"? Flask runs on the server, it serves a request every time a browser visits, but it doesn't know or care when that browser was started.

Comment: `z=x+y` gets executed exactly once because it is evaluated when Python first runs the script, and then never again.

Comment: (Of course, this code doesn't actually work because `x` and `y` are not defined at module scope; maybe we would be able to help better if you posted real code?)

Comment: @tripleee all the functions get executed twice. When I run the program all the functions get executed once and the server starts on web browser. But the page is empty. If I press refresh entire code runs again and I see the result

Comment: @DanielRoseman I cant post the real code here since it is more than 800 lines. Thats the reason my code is taking a lot of time to run twice and Im searching if there's a way to avoid it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call functions within home route. Like below:

```
def func1():
    return x
def func2():
    return y

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    x = func1()
    y = func2()
    z = x + y
    return render_template('home.html', z=z, x=x, y=y)
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: I actually have two flask functions and the second function also needs the data. If that data was defined inside home() will it be available for product()?

Comment: make a separate function for the common data or processing, and then you can call that function from home() as well as from product() to get value and pass on to each templates

Comment: Is there a way to pass data from one flask function to another?. Say for example I have a flask function for login and it accepts username and password. Can that username and password be saved and passed to another function?

Comment: There are many ways you can do that. You can use flask-login extension if you want to save current user info. Or you can save particular info in session if you moving across pages. If you staying on same page, you can keep that info in any variable or can create User class, and can have that info in its object. There are tons of examples on google if you search by these names. Also, if my answers have helped your original query then don't shy to accept it.